# Picking random record from Entity Framework database without OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I try to get random record from database:

```
 personToCall = db.Persons.Skip(toSkip).Take(1).First();
```

but I get exception which tells me:

```
{"The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'."}
```

Can I do it without `OrderBy`? Sorting data structure (O(nlogn)) to pick random element(which should be constant) doesn't look wise.

**EDIT:** I use Entity Framework 6.1.1.

Comment: Do you use `Identity` integer primary keys?

Comment: Both the answers below should work for you .

Comment: @Lukazoid Didn't hear about them. The model looks like `public class Person {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        etc....}` and Entity Framework created table basing on this code.

Comment: Even if you do I don't see how that would help. If they were guaranteed to be sequential and without gaps you could find the max and min with an efficient index operation then select a random number in that range with a seek. But they aren't guaranteed to be.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can have something like :

```
personToCall = db.Persons.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Skip(toSkip).Take(1).First();
```

You should use `FirstOrDefault` to be mode defensive.

Here the dark lord teaching the force to yoda! what is the world coming to!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is dependent on the version of Entity Framework that the OP is using.

Comment: @JustinNiessner I use EF 6.1.1.

Comment: DarthVader will this LINQ query make any changes to my table?

Comment: Thanks. Does it make any difference in efficiency if I write: `db.Persons.OrderBy(r => r.Id).Skip(toSkip).Take(1).First();` instead of NewGuid version?

Comment: It could avoid a sort if the id is indexed. But to get a truly random appropriate value to use for toSkip you would need to count the rows first. So that would take 1.5 passes through the data on average.

Comment: Haha, the last line is just too funny

Comment: this is a good solution if you have ~1000 records or don't care about your CPU and time

Answer (score 6):

First you need to get the random number from 1 to max record, see this

```
Random rand = new Random();
int toSkip = rand.Next(0, db.Persons.Count());

db.Persons.Skip(toSkip).Take(1).First();
```

with order by you can use the Guid.NewGuid()

```
db.Persons.OrderBy(x=>x.Guid.NewGuid()).Skip(toSkip).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This is simple and good, but it should be rand.Next(0, ...) or the first record will never be included

Comment: However, I noticed now that this becomes slow when the number of records increases, I now have approx 30,000 and it's too slow so I have to give up on this method

Comment: A set of parenthesis are needed after `Count` on the second line of the example code.

Answer (score 5):

**There is no way to do this without an ordering clause.**

personToCall = db.Persons.OrderBy(r => Random.Next()).First();

That could be slow depending on the size of your Persons table, so if you wanted to make this fast, you'd have to add a column to Person, or join it to a dictionary of random numbers and Person keys, then order by that.  But that is rarely a wise solution.

Better to ask a higher level question about the overall task at hand.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the OrderBy, dump to a List and random pick against the Index:

VB

```
With New List(Of Persons)
    .AddRange(db.Persons)
    PersonToCall = .Item(New Random().Next(0, .Count - 1))
End With
```

C#

```
var people = new List<Persons>();
people.AddRange(db.Persons);
personToCall  = people.Item(new Random().Next(0, people.Count - 1));
```

Comment: If fetching the whole table doesn't scale for your purposes, another thought might be to have a View in your model on the database side:

    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table ORDER BY NEWID()