# Why I can't get random rows using EF Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am about to get 6 random rows using EF Core (v5.0.4).

Here are columns in my table:

```
int id(primary key,auto increase)
varchar title
```

Most of the tutorials (like [Picking random record from Entity Framework database without OrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835184/picking-random-record-from-entity-framework-database-without-orderby)) suggest using `OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())`

Here is my code:

```
Context.topics.Where(//some logic).OrderBy(X => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(6);
```

However, in my project, this always returns the same rows without random results.

What's wrong with it? Thank you.

Comment: For me, this code worked well.You can check the data of the query again.Or you can provide other more details.

Comment: this should work, the generated query is like appended with `ORDER BY NEWID()`. So this means your sql provider does not support it. What I tested is for Sql Server. What provider do you use? If it's not an issue of the provider, you surely tested it wrong and ended up with a wrong assumption.

Comment: What I am using is Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.0-alpha.2 for asp.net core 5@KingKing

Comment: @KingKing I tried another way by Context.topics.Where(//some logic).ToList() then orderby GUID and it doesn't work also.

Comment: if it does not even work for linq-to-object (orderby after `ToList()`). Then there must be something special to your data making you think that the order is not randomly changed. I doubt that you may look at some columns which have duplicate data. That causes wrong assumption.

Comment: @KingKing Yes! There are so many duplicate data but with not the same id. However, how can I solve this? It seems it is needless for me to select a new one.

Comment: @KingKing Now I have to do it like this:Context.Topics.Where(//some logic).Select(_ => new Models.RandomTopic() { id = _.id, TopicTitle = _.title }).ToList().OrderBy(_ => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(6).ToArray() . It won't work without the ToList() and I don't know why.

Comment: @KingKing It seems it is because of this problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714933/random-order-with-entity-framework-and-mysql